# Problema con json_decode() me altera un key "0" de numero string de JSON en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, base-de-datos

Necesito llamar este valor registrado en una columna de MySQL:

```
{"0":[{"Type":3,"Seconds":-185}],"1":[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]}
```

De esta forma obtengo el JSON desde la base de datos de MySQL:

```
$boosterResultant = json_encode($mysqli->query('SELECT boosters FROM player_equipment WHERE userId = '.$player['userId'].'')->fetch_assoc()['boosters']); //response: "{\"0\":[{\"Type\":3,\"Seconds\":-185}],\"1\":[{\"Type\":4,\"Seconds\":-144}]}"
```

Quiero acceder a lo que hay en 'Seconds' para modificar su valor y que el objeto no sea modificado sino unicamente ese valor, asi que lo edito de esta manera:

```
$boosterFinal = json_decode($boosterResultant,true);
$boosterFinal['0'][0]['Seconds'] += 36000; //el valor se modifica correctamente
echo "Resultado:", json_encode($boosterFinal); //output: [[{"Type":3,"Seconds":35815}],[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]]
```

Desde que ejecuto `$boosterFinal = json_decode($boosterResultant,true);` me trae esto: `[[{"Type":3,"Seconds":-185}],[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]]` y necesito que me quede así para sobreescribirlo en la base de datos:

```
{"0":[{"Type":3,"Seconds":35815}],"1":[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]} //bien
//mal: [[{"Type":3,"Seconds":35815}],[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]]
```

Comment: Todo esta bien solo que en tu caso accedes con `"0"` como cadena, ahora debes de acceder a el con `0` como entero y listo.

Comment: Usandolo de esta forma: `$boosterFinal[0][0]['Seconds'] += 36000;` también obtengo lo mismo: `[[{"Type":3,"Seconds":35815}],[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]]`, necesito que el key "0" y el key "1" no se eliminen y quede así: `{"0":[{"Type":3,"Seconds":35815}],"1":[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás convirtiendo tu JSON a array cuando pasas `TRUE` a `json_decode`, como bien indica la documentación. Eso significa que luego tengas que recovertir el objeto para darle su forma original para guardarlo de nuevo, modificado, en la base de datos.

La conversión no es necesaria, más bien lo que hace es complicar el trabajo.

He aquí un ejemplo donde trabajas con el JSON tal cual, modificas lo que haga falta y lo tienes en su estado original para devolverlo a la base de datos:

```
#Este es tu dato original venido de la BD
$str='{"0":[{"Type":3,"Seconds":-185}],"1":[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]}';
#No pasas TRUE a json_decode para trabajar como JSON tal cual
$mJson=json_decode($str);
#Como ejemplo, modifcamos Seconds en el índice 0
$mJson->{0}[0]->Seconds+=36000;
#Prueba del objeto
var_dump($mJson);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["0"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
      ["Type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["Seconds"]=>
      int(35815)
    }
  }
  ["1"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
      ["Type"]=>
      int(4)
      ["Seconds"]=>
      int(-144)
    }
  }
}
```

### Conclusión

Como muestra el `var_dump`, el objeto no fue modificado en su naturaleza, conserva su estado original y `Seconds` en el índice `0` ha sido modificado adecuadamente (su valor actual es `35815`). Ahora puedes devolver `$mJson` a la BD con la misma estructura que tenía en su origen.

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar los indices tienes dos opciones dependiendo de tu versión de php

```
// ^7.3
json_encode($boosterFinal, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

// Anterior a 7.3
json_encode((object)$boosterFinal);
```

Comment: He usado esta forma ya que mi PHP es mayor a la versión 7.3: `$boosterResultant = $mysqli->query('SELECT boosters FROM player_equipment WHERE userId = '.$player['userId'].'')->fetch_assoc()['boosters'];`

`$boosterFinal = json_decode($boosterResultant, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`, sigo obteniendo esto como salida desde la BD: `[[{"Type":3,"Seconds":-185}],[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]] `